# PHP login with PDO, doesnt seem to work

Tags: php, pdo

There aren't any errors given, but for some reason the code doesnt seem to work..

Here is the code:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('inc/db.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location: index.php");
} else {
    try {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $SQL = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =:username AND password =:password');
        $SQL->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $SQL->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $SQL->execute();
        $total = $SQL->rowCount();
        $row = $SQL->fetch();

        if($total > 0) {
            if($row['verified'] > 0) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            } else {
                echo "Unverified";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect";
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {

    }
}

?>
```

Can anyone help me see what's wrong? Thank you a lot in advance :)

EDIT::::

Here is my db.php

```
<?php
try {
    $DB_NAME = 'users';
    $DB_USER = 'root';
    $DB_PASS = '';
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error?";
}
?>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `try .. catch` stuff and then you might see some errors. You also don't need `mysql_real_escape_string()` when using parameter binding

Comment: I'd put debug into the catch clause instead of removing the try-catch block (`echo $e->getMessage();`)

Comment: @ChrisForrence No, no, no! If there's an error, exceptions should occur. Why get rid of valuable information by replacing it with an `echo`? If you're not going to deal with an exception with the view to continue normal program operation, you should let the exception go.

Comment: @Phil - I agree that exceptions occur on errors, but I disagree on removing handling of exceptions. I could see where my statement may not be ideal (could also print out $e->errorInfo()), but it would let the program continue executing and possibly recover (possibly by returning an error message), which is what you'd want in an application.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Once you reach the level of handling application errors, you would use a broader `try..catch` block that could catch any `Exception`, log the details, alert the relevant parties and show a nice, friendly error message. If all you're doing is `echo $e->getMessage()`, you're doing it wrong

Comment: You shouldn't store plain-text passwords in your database.

Comment: *There aren't any errors given* - so what's the output of your script? if empty, either the user is verified or the code hit your empty `catch {}` block.

Answer (score 2):

This should serve you better and identify errors if and when they occur

```
<?php
// inc/db.php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

and your main file

```
<?php
// Remove these two lines when you've finished development
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Required POST parameters not present');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/db.php';

$SQL = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password');
$SQL->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$SQL->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password']);
$SQL->execute();
$row = $SQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($row !== false) {
    if ($row['verified'] > 0) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        // you probably want to redirect here or something
    } else {
        echo 'Unverified';
    }
} else {
    echo "Incorrect";
}
```

Comment: Ideally `error_reporting` and `display_errors` should be configured using either php.ini or .htaccess-alike files. It's too easy to leave debug code in place :)

Comment: Also, why did you remove the `:` prefix of the bound parameter names? PDO will add them, but I wouldn't recommend relying on that behaviour :)

Comment: @Jack Totally agree about the error reporting. Ideally, this is configured at the environment level. I just like using the actual parameter name and not the `:parameter_name` syntax as syntactically it makes more sense (to me). As you said, either is valid and supported. The code is here - https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L363

Comment: Yeah, I know the code. I favour the second branch of that condition, that's all :)

Comment: @Jack In the interest of micro-optimising, I've added the colons back in :)

Comment: Hurray for micro optimisation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

first of all you can safely remove the following statements. the parameters are already escaped by PDO. you don't have to do it using obsolete methods. that method will also not work if you don't have an active mysql connection

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

secondly your script suggest that you have not encrypted your passwords and have stored them using plain text. this can be a big security issue since anyone who has access to your database can see the users passwords.

Thirdly i suggest you echo `$e->getMessage()` in your catch block to see if there is any exception thrown.

Comment: I just posted my db.php, I think i do have an active connection

Comment: You have an active PDO connection, not an active mysql connection.

Comment: Not only is escaping unnecessary when you use parametrized statements, it's wrong -- if it worked, your values would get escaped twice.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean?

Comment: @DevZer0 I am not using md5() or sha1() at the moment, just to make sure this works firstly...

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` will only work after you have called `mysql_connect()`. Using `new PDO` doesn't do that. They are two completely different APIs to the MySQL database.

Comment: @rshah i suggest you use `PASSWORD` function in mysql it self. It generates much stronger hashes.

Comment: Okay, I will do all the security related issues once it works, but for now, how could i make it work? It doesnt seem to throw any errors :s

Comment: well you need to read my 3rd point

Comment: I entered the url like this: /login.php?username=lol&password=lol

and i get this:

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\descchat\login.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\descchat\login.php on line 12
Incorrect

Comment: you need to use form post